# Is it possible to modify the properties that are returned for the joined objects that have WHERE clause?

Tags: aqueduct

I have been trying to change the returned properties of a joined object, considering that it has a filter from a WHERE clause. However this was not possible directly because the WHERE clause returns a QueryExpression class and not the Query class that has the returningProperties method.

I tried according to the code below:

```
var query = Query<Obj1>(context)
    ..where((o) => o.state).equalTo(state);
    query.join(set: (q) => q.objs2)
    ..where((a) => a.state).equalTo(state)
    ..returningProperties((a) => [a.id, a.description, a.answer]);
  var results = await query.fetch();
```

I was able to perform the query doing the following:

```
var query = Query<Obj1>(context)
    ..where((o) => o.state).equalTo(state);
    Query<Obj2> subQuery = query.join(set: (q) => q.objs2)
    ..where((a) => a.state).equalTo(state)
    ..returningProperties((a) => [a.id, a.description, a.answer]);
  var results = await query.fetch();
```

My question is, is there another way to do this? What have I done is correct? Is it possible to have a simpler or more direct way of putting these clauses together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what correct is without knowing the intent of the query. Both of the queries you've listed are identical as far as I can tell; based on the error message you provided, you may have previously had an error that you fixed (the first `where` was missing `equalTo`).

The query you have here finds all `Obj1`s whose `state` is `state`. Then it joins the `objs2` for each, but only the `Obj2` whose `state` is `state`. The returned `Obj2` have only their `id`, `description` and `answer` populated.

I'd suggest using the latter of your two examples - where you extract the subquery into a variable. It makes the query easier to modify, and lots of intermixed dot and cascade operators make code hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion. The first query I made a syntax error, however I posted here the code without error, by mistake. Anyway thank you.